# Parabola Orientation polyfit/polyval (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit a parabola using `polyfit/polyval` combination in Matlab. However, in some cases, I am not able to align the peak of fitted parabola as it should be with the given data. As an example, please see the attached image. Any idea to fix this problem?

My data points are as follows:

x = 4.13, 5.19, 5.79, 5.83, 5.51, 4.98, 4.35

y = 270, 285, 300, 315, 330, 345, 360

[image]

Comment: Your question needs more details, such as your code and the coordinates of the points you are trying to fit, to be answerable. Please [edit] your code to include a [mre]. If you are confident your code is correct, then have you considered the possibility that the calculated parabola _is_ the actual least-squares best fit to your known points?

Comment: Have you posted just a snippet near the peak of a larger plot? I.e., does polyfit produce a solution that works well overall, but just doesn't give you the peak exactly where you wanted?  Maybe you want a constrained fit with the peak position specified?

Comment: I am using peak of the given data and forcing it into polyfit.

Comment: @Paranav. I am fitting the parabola fairly successfully in most cases. it is just those few cases where the peak of the fitted parabola is not appearing where I desire it to appear. How can I apply least square fit? Any ideas?

Comment: Where are the data points on your figure ?

Comment: @JJ: Please see the data points for which I was trying to fit the parabola.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the axis of the parabola is horizontal the equation is :

[image]

Linear least mean squares fitting gives the values of the three parameters.

[image]

If you want a more accurate fitting with non-horizontal axis (general cubic section curve), see page 16 in https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14819165/Regressions-coniques-quadriques-circulaire-spherique

[image]

Comment: Of course beware of overfitting... the second model has 5 coefficients and 7 input points may not be enough.

Comment: Thanks JJ. I think the second solution looks more appealing to me.